# Python dataframe converting time date 'SylmiSeb' (2018-12-31 23:43:02+00:00) to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a column of the style `2018-12-31 23:43:02+00:00` to `2018-12-31` by using **pd.to_datetime** . I got this database by using snscrape library (https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape).

However when I try this:

```
database_2018['date_created'] =  
pd.to_datetime(database_2018['date_created'], 
infer_datetime_format=True)
```

I get the following error: **ParserError: Unknown string format: SylmiSeb**

When I ask the dtype of this column date it appears as an object type. Any ideas on how to solve this?

I also tried:

```
 database_2018['date_created'] =   
 pd.Timestamp(database_2018['date_created'])
 .to_datetime()
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [0         2018-12-31 23:43:02+00:00
1         2018-12-31 23:30:20+00:00
2         2018-12-31 23:30:00+00:00
3         2018-12-31 23:28:09+00:00
4         2018-12-31 23:28:08+00:00
                    ...            
105037    2018-01-01 00:29:18+00:00
105038    2018-01-01 00:25:04+00:00
105039    2018-01-01 00:10:03+00:00
105040    2018-01-01 00:03:28+00:00
105041    2018-01-01 00:00:44+00:00
Name: date_created, Length: 105042, dtype: object] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
database_2018['date_created'] = database_2018['date_created'].apply(
    lambda x: x[:x.rfind(':')] + x[x.rfind(':')+1:]
)

database_2018['date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(
database_2018['date_created'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

This is the format of your dates, where %z represents UTC offset. For more information, see datetime [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). The UTC offset needs to be without the colon character.  So the first part of the code above removes that colon.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried it but I got this error=> ValueError: time data 'SylmiSeSylmiSeb' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z' (match)

Comment: You have that string somewhere in that column and pandas cannot parse it as a datetime value. So you can manually remove or edit that value and try again, or use `errors='coerce'` as an additional argument in the `pd.to_datetime()` function, which will convert that value to null (`NaT`).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC You are trying to fetch only date from a datetime column with timezone.

**Setup**

```
d="""date_created
2018-12-31 23:30:20+00:00
2018-12-31 23:30:00+00:00
2018-12-31 23:28:09+00:00
2018-12-31 23:28:08+00:00"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df

    date_created
0   2018-12-31 23:30:20+00:00
1   2018-12-31 23:30:00+00:00
2   2018-12-31 23:28:09+00:00
3   2018-12-31 23:28:08+00:00
```

**Code**

**Option 1**

```
df['date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_created,errors='coerce').dt.date
df
```

**Output**

```
    date_created
0   2018-12-31
1   2018-12-31
2   2018-12-31
3   2018-12-31
```

**Option 2, if we want to remove timezone**

For timezone understanding, if you want to just remove timezone.

```
df['date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_created,errors='coerce').dt.tz_localize(None)
df
```

**Output**

```
    date_created
0   2018-12-31 23:30:20
1   2018-12-31 23:30:00
2   2018-12-31 23:28:09
3   2018-12-31 23:28:08
```